# Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $M^+(\mathbb{R})$ proove that $ \displaystyle{\int \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int f_n}$

Tags: lebesgue-integral

How to prove the following exercise:

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $M^+(\mathbb{R})$ proove that $ \displaystyle{\int \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int f_n}$

it reminds me the Lebesgue's Monotone Convergence Theorem:

Let $\{f_n ,n =1,2,...,\}$be a sequence of non-negative measurable fucntions such that $\{f_n(x)\}$ is monotone increasing for each $x$. Let $ f = \lim f_n$. Then $\int f= \lim \int f_n$

we can define a sequence $s_k$ of partial sums such that $\displaystyle{s_k = \sum_{n=1}^{k}f_n}$  so $s_k$ satisfies the theorem hipothesis. But how to proceed with $f = \lim f_n$? In this case $\displaystyle{ \lim s_k = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n } = s$ (is that correct?)
and applying the theorem:
\begin{array} {lcl} \int s & = & \lim\int{s_k}  \\ \displaystyle{\int \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n} & = &  \displaystyle{\lim \int \sum_{n=1}^{k} f_n} \\  & = &  \displaystyle{\lim\int (f_1+f_2+\ldots+f_k)}   \\ &=& \displaystyle{\lim(\int f_1 +\int f_2+\ldots+\int f_k)} \\ & = & \displaystyle{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int f_n}&\end{array}

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: may you give me please some suggestions in order to improve the proof?